# Qual a origem e significado da palavra "caipira"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia

Em algumas ocasiões é comum verificar um sentido pejorativo pra palavra caipira, porém também é comum ver a palavra relacionada a "cultura caipira", que normalmente se refere a vida no campo, a simplicidade das pessoas que vivem no interior e coisas assim.

De onde veio a palavra? Originalmente ela surgiu como ofensa?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caipira#Etimologia

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em relação ao uso pejorativo, complementando e baseando-me no que o Orion disse sobre a palavra tupi original significar "habitante do mato", uma pessoa pode ser chamada de "caipira" pejorativamente, querendo dizer que a pessoa a quem é direcionada "vive no mato", ou seja, fica "fora da civilização", ou ainda que é um "bicho do mato".

Geralmente algumas pessoas chamam alguma outra de caipira quando essa pessoa, por exemplo, fica completamente impressionada com tecnologias simples, ou ainda uma pessoa que não gosta de sair de casa, ou também uma pessoa tímida e acanhada.

Porém esses usos e significados podem variar de pessoa para pessoa.

O [Dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/caipira) lista mais alguns dos possíveis usos pejorativos:

> 2. Que ou quem tem modos considerados rústicos, simples, grosseiros ou incultos.
> 3. Que ou quem revela falta de requinte ou de bom gosto. = BREGA, CAFONA
> 4. Que ou quem é tímido, pouco sociável.

Quanto a se originalmente a palavra "caipira" surgiu como ofensa: [não](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/es/v32n115/v32n115a14.pdf), esse termo foi usado desde os tempos coloniais para se referir aos moradores da roça.

Answer (score 8):

Caipira é um termo de origem tupi que designa, desde os tempos coloniais brasileiros, os moradores da roça. A designação alcançou, sobretudo, populações da antiga capitania de São Vicente (posteriormente capitania de São Paulo) que hoje são os estados de Santa Catarina, Paraná, São Paulo, Mato Grosso do Sul, Minas Gerais, Goiás, Mato Grosso, Tocantins e Rondônia.

O termo "caipira", no entanto, costuma ser utilizado com mais frequência para se referir à população do interior dos estados de São Paulo, Paraná, Mato Grosso do Sul, Goiás e Minas Gerais.

Existem várias explicações etimológicas para a origem do termo "caipira", sempre a partir da língua tupi:

- ka'apir ou kaa - pira, que significa "cortador de mato";
- ka'a pora, "habitante do mato", a partir da junção de caa (mato) e pora (gente).

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caipira

Comment: Ok. Mas será que existe alguma origem para o uso pejorativo? Como na sentença "João é muito caipira mesmo. Nunca sai de casa" ou "Você fala muito devagar, parece caipira" e coisas desse tipo

Answer (score 2):

A mais remota citação ao termo "caipira" que encontramos, em 1822, em São Paulo, teria sido ouvido por Saint-Hilarie como xingamento dos paulistas a pessoas de vilas vizinhas, feias e maltrapilhas - mas que só após 1828 o cientista teria feito um substancial estudo sobre a palavra "caipira" e constatado não ser originariamente indígena (conforme hoje é sempre citado), mas uma corruptela de "corupira" - um "daemon" das matas, termo recolhido dos índios em São Paulo por José de Anchieta (1812 [1560], p. 161-162 - em latim) - citado "curupira" - um espírito maligno - por Simão de Vasconcellos (1865 [1662], p. 100) e como "coropira"  - o próprio diabo, termo recolhido na região amazônica pelo jesuíta João Daniel (1975 [1757], p. 239). Este último registrou ainda que os índios mais selvagens eram chamados pelos índios aldeiados de "caaporas". Saint-Hilare observara ainda ser "caipira" xingamento político utilizado em Portugal aos dissidentes de Pedro I, entre 1828/1832 (SAINT-HILARE, 1851, Tomo I, p.275-276) - mas possivelmente este tratamento entre políticos rivais já fosse utilizado antes, posto termos em 1823 encontrado o termo num texto sobre política no jornal O Tamoyo (1823, nº 5, p.6) e em 1824 nos registros de uma embarcação que constantemente saía dos portos cariocas a "Sumaca Caipira" - jornal Diário do Rio de Janeiro (1824, ed 5000008, p. 4).

Comment: João, bem-vindo ao site. Isto é muito interessante. Mas deves indicar a origem. Isto parece ter sido tirado dalgum livro, artigo, tese de mestrado ou coisa assim Nesse caso deves indicar a fonte, para as pessoas poderem conferir e ver mais, e para não seres acusado de plágio. O texto parece também conter referências bibliográficas incompletas, com o nome do autor, ano e página mas sem o título da obra.

Answer (score 2):

Jacinto: sim, o texto é de uma monografia - uma monografia MINHA! Chama-se LINHA DO TEMPO DA VIOLA NO BRASIL, depositada em 2021. Achei interessante solicitarem-me nomes dos livros, visto que o próprio texto base e os demais comentários não apontam terem surgido de qualquer literatura de época, são só teorias tardias aos fatos - já meu comentário é embasado em fontes DE ÉPOCA, eu li os citados livros e vários outros (em latim, francês, inglês, alemão, etc); claramente, aponto usar metodologia científica (formato ABNT de referências). Curioso isso...
Há resistência, pelo entendimento coletivo sobre "caipira" ser agradável a muitos, há várias décadas, é compreensível... Nenhum dicionário sério de tupi aponta que a palavra seja indígena, porque assim como "caipira", não é, nem nunca foi - e só pela interpretação de C. Pires seria uma "cultura" (mérito dele, era um vendedor genial). Assim, agrada a muitos acreditar que seja, inclusive estudiosos - mas não se comprova historicamente, por fontes de época. Quer saber se era palavra indígena? Leia o que escreveu quem conviveu com índios - que são os que indiquei.

Comment: Olá João Araújo e obrigado pelo contributo. Estou a ler o trabalho que citas e parece excelente! Este site tem um formato próprio em que naturalmente é preferivel serem incluidas referências nas respostas, em especial quando é citado material de artigo ou livro para clarificar a sua origem.

Comment: O comentário do Jacinto no teu post anterior não foi nada de pessoal, qualquer um dos utilizadores habituais do site teria deixado um comentário semelhante se tivesse visto a tua resposta antes do Jacinto. A razão do comentário é ser política da rede StackExchange - por ter dezenas de milhões de posts- exigir referências para respostas que pareçam conter material de outros autores quando a sua origem não é evidente. (Por exemplo [podes ver aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749/) como ainda há uns meses a rede investiu em melhores mecanismos de sinalização de pelágio).

Comment: Olá João! Obrigado por retornar e por responder ao comentário do Jacinto à sua resposta. Como bad_coder já explicou, o pedido de referências mais completas é de praxe por aqui, não é pessoal: Por favor inclua os títulos das obras citadas. Como o texto é retirado de um já existente, por favor também inclua uma referência à obra, preferencialmente com um link para o repositório oficial (numa busca rápida a encontro apenas no [docplayer](https://docplayer.com.br/228984471-Joao-araujo-linha-do-tempo-da-viola-no-brasil-a-consolidacao-da-familia-das-violas-brasileiras-belo-horizonte-mg-2021.html)).

Answer (score -1):

O Dicionário vai ter que buscar mais informações para definir e atualizar a palavra "Caipira".

E o que é ser um Caipira?

Primeiro: Nos dias atuais o caipira é mais um tipo,o caipira não é mais uma pessoa rude, aliás nesse tempo todos eram caipira, porque praticamente todos eram rude e de pouca informação...

Não é demérito ser chamado de caipira... 
Ser caipira é ser autentico, ser verdadeiro, puro e acima de tudo sábio!

A palavra Caipira surgiu da lenda do Caipora. Caipora era um homem que ao nascer perdeu seus pais, acabou adotado pelos macacos,lá cresceu e viveu como se fosse macaco. Tempos depois já na terceira idade foi descoberto por caçadores, que vendo aquele homem cabeludo, estranho saíram correndo e o caipora também assustado com aquela espécie parecida com ele, correu em direção oposta, daí surgiu a história do caipira que veio do CAIPORA...

Comment: consegue alguma referência sobre essa lenda?